# How to draw network cluster using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I try to create a network simulation using MATLAB. I want to display all nodes and cluster heads and the connection between those two like the picture below.

[image]

The problem is I can't draw the lines between all cluster heads (dotted blue) to base stations (red cross).
Below is the code I tried:

```
subplot(2,2,3);
for i=1:numel(MCH(10,:))
    if(isfield(MCH{10,i},'x'))
        MCHX = [MCHX C{10,i}.x];
        MCHY = [MCHY C{10,i}.y];
        plot([MCH{10,i}.x sink.x],[MCH{10,i}.y sink.y],'-black');
    end
end
```

It seems like `plot` only draws the last line.

Any idea how to solve this problem? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hold on`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) to retain everything you draw in the plot:

```
subplot(2,2,3);
hold on;
for i=1:numel(MCH(10,:))
    if(isfield(MCH{10,i},'x'))
        MCHX = [MCHX C{10,i}.x];
        MCHY = [MCHY C{10,i}.y];
        plot([MCH{10,i}.x sink.x],[MCH{10,i}.y sink.y],'-black');
    end
end
```